# Newton's Laws confusion

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity

Suppose I push myself against the Earth:

- Am I pushing the Earth away OR
- Is it the Earth pushing me away?

Comment: It's not an either-or question. The answer is "yes".

Comment: It is an either-or question.

Comment: Just because you are trying making it one does not mean that it is.

Comment: The person who asks the question decides what kind of question it is, ryt?

Comment: Your confusion results from trying to create a mutually exclusive outcome where doing so is incorrect. By Newton's third law, object A responds to the force exerted on it by object B, while object B responds to the equal but opposite force exerted on it by object A.

Comment: Regarding asking questions, I can ask a question like "Is Mr. A an idiot *or* a madman ?".  But just because I phrase a question and limit the possible answers I want, doesn't mean that the correct answer is one of those.  That's what you've done here : tried to limit the answers to one of two choices, when the correct answer is not one of two ( as @David-Hammen explains ).

Comment: @David Hammen ok but you should have said "both" not "yes".

Comment: @DavidHammen (correctly so) means "yes" as in "yes for both". I don't see the source of your confusion. The two statements of your question are complementary, not exclusive.

Comment: @PhyEnthusiast Well he did say "it's not an either or question".  The response of "the answer is yes" was a tongue in cheek way of saying the question was poorly formed.  You shouldn't usually be able to answer an either or question with "yes" but in this context it makes some sense (and added a little humour).  He also only left it as a comment so it really shouldn't have been a comprehensive answer; but pointing out the error in the question could help you understand why it was ill-posed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose I push myself against the Earth:

- I push the Earth away

**AND**

- The Earth pushes  me away with a force of the same magnitude and opposite in direction.

This is Newton's third law in action.

Answer (score 2):

Both. Force is defined as a rate of change of momentum, and net momentum change must be zero as momentum is conserved. If you and the earth can be seen to have momentum $0$ at $t=0$, at $t=t$ where you have jumped, and have upwards momentum, the earth must have 'downwards' momentum, such that $p_{net} = 0$ [and thus since each individual object has been subject to the same change of momentum, both have been subject to equal and opposite forces].